# Angular - How to unify auth observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angularfire2

I have an Angular service that uses AngularFire's auth observable to listen to state changes of the user. When a user signs in, the app must fetch a user document from MongoDB. This data needs to be consumable by components, so I need to have another observable. The problem is, I'm not quite sure how to make it work.

Here is a snippet of my auth service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../interfaces/User.model'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  public redirectRoute = ''
  public loginError = '';
  public _mongoUser: Observable<User | null> = of(null);
  public mongoUser: User | null = null;

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient,) {

    this.auth.user.subscribe(async (user) => {
      console.log('auth changed', user)
      if (user) {

        let headers = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .set('idToken', await user.getIdToken())
        }

        this._mongoUser = this.http.post<User>(
          `${environment.apiUrl}/users/email/${user.email}`,
          { personal: { email: user.email } },
          headers
        )

        this._mongoUser.subscribe(val => {
          console.log('val', val)
          this.mongoUser = val
        })

      } else {

      }
    })
  }

}
```

The main question is, how should I initialize _mongoUser? I think using of... and then the httpClient method is not working the way I want it to.

I want to consume _mongoUser or mongoUser like this in other components. However, my code above does not work.

```
constructor() {
    this.authService._mongoUser.subscribe(val => {    
      if (val) {
        this.editForm.patchValue({ 'username': val.username })
      }

    })
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reassigning to `this._mongoUser`, you are throwing away all of the subscriptions that were made before the reassignment.

To avoid reassignment, you can use a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`. In this case, I think `BehaviorSubject` would be a better fit. It keeps track of the most recently emitted item and

1. re-emits that item to new subscribers
2. [lets you synchronously access that item with the `BehaviorSubject#getValue` method](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject#getvalue-)

Here is a version of your example that is modified to use `BehaviorSubject`.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, filter, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../interfaces/User.model'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  public redirectRoute = ''
  public loginError = '';

  // readonly so we never reassign this field
  public readonly mongoUser: BehaviorSubject<User | null> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient,) {
    this.auth.user.pipe(
      tap((user) => console.log('auth changed', user)),
      filter((user) => !!user),
      mergeMap(async (user) => ({ user, idToken: await user.getIdToken()})),
      mergeMap(({user, idToken}) => {
        let headers = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .set('idToken', idToken)
        }

        return this.http.post<User>(
          `${environment.apiUrl}/users/email/${user.email}`,
          { personal: { email: user.email } },
          headers
        )
      }),
    ).subscribe({
        next: (userFromApi) => this.mongoUser.next(userFromApi)
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think the readonly is very clever!

Answer (score 1):

#### Reassigning Objects

In Javascript, if you have a reference to an object and it gets re-assigned, you don't get a new reference.

```ts
let exampleObject = {Hello: "World"};
const ref = exampleObject;
exampleObject = {New: "Value"};

console.log("ref: ", ref); // ref: {"Hello":"World"}
console.log("eo : ", exampleObject); // eo : {"New":"Value"}
```

So you don't want to re-assign `public _mongoUser` since other services may have an outdated reference.

You can use a behaviorSubject instead:

```ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  public redirectRoute = ''
  public loginError = '';
  public _mongoUser = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);
  public mongoUser: User | null = null;

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient,) {

    this.auth.user.pipe(
      map(user => user.getIdToken().pipe(
        map(idToken => ({user, idToken}))
      ))
    ).subscribe(({user, idToken}) => {
      console.log('auth changed', user)
      if (user) {

        let headers = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .set('idToken', idToken)
        }

        this.http.post<User>(
          `${environment.apiUrl}/users/email/${user.email}`,
          { personal: { email: user.email } },
          headers
        ).subscribe(this._mongoUser.next.bind(this._mongoUser));

        this._mongoUser.subscribe(val => {
          console.log('val', val)
          this.mongoUser = val
        })

      } else {

      }
    })
  }

}
```

#### Some Cleanup

Above is the minimal changes that should get things started, but there are a few places you can use RxJS to simplify your code further:

```ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  public redirectRoute = ''
  public loginError = '';
  public _mongoUser = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);
  public mongoUser: User | null = null;

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient,) {
    
    this._mongoUser.subscribe(val => {
      console.log('val', val)
      this.mongoUser = val
    });

    this.auth.user.pipe(
      filter(user => user != null),
      map(user => user.getIdToken().pipe(
        map(idToken => ({
          user, 
          headers: { 
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('idToken', idToken) 
          }
        }))
      )),
      concatMap(({user, headers}) => this.http.post<User>(
        `${environment.apiUrl}/users/email/${user.email}`,
        { personal: { email: user.email } },
        headers
      ))
    ).subscribe(
      this._mongoUser.next.bind(this._mongoUser)
    );
  }
  
}
```